# Generating Google Analytics from a C# Application

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I would like to be able to generate Google analytics data that will show me number of startups of my application but also the time it tool for each starup and the average time for all startups.  Something like:

```
Startups      1296

Startup Times
40ms
27ms
128ms
700ms
42ms
82ms
...
...
127ms (Average)
```

I know it is possible to get the Startups but not sure if it is possible to also get Startup Times.  Is it possible to do this and how from a C# desktop application?

Comment: That is correct.  I am planning to use it for few things one of which is in the description above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am developing a lib called gappalytics, it allows you to **log analytics events for desktop apps**. Link to package [nuget.org/Gappalytics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gappalytics/). 
Usage sample: [github.org/gapalytics](https://github.com/Vasiliauskas/Gappalytics)

Comment: Is it open source?  Can it do what I am asking above?  Thanks

Comment: It is Open. You can log startup times as events, just use stopwatch to calculate them inside the app.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: How does gapalytics account for sessions and other things that are typically web like (for instance URLs for pages)? I see the info on the github page for sessions, but what should be on the GA side when I set up the tracking id for "domain"? Does that have to be valid and does it have to match what I pass when I set up the session?

Comment: You do not need a valid domain, gappalytics also will keep session tracking the same way as javascript does for webpages by storing unique session hashes by time, visit count, first visit time.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can sent http request in realtime (or a [narrowly defined offset window](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt)) you can use the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). I don't think there is a C# client library, but this is basically just a http request with the parameters and and such its language agnostic.

There are a few required parameters - the protocol version (always v1 for now), Google Account ID, a unique Client ID per user or device and a hit type (pageview, screen, event, transaction etc.). Also depending on the hit type you need additional parameters (document location/page title, event category/action/label etc.).

There is a [parameter reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) with all possible fields, and you can construct hits for testing via the [hit builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/).

Google Analytics has a "[user timings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#timing)" hit type (basically you pass a description and a duration in microseconds), so the report from your example should be very easily doable.

I don't know C#, but I'm reasonably certain is has a way to format a string as an url with parameters and send an http request, and in the end that's really all you need for data collection with GA.